# Write multiple lines to text file with '\n'

Tags: file-io, newline, rust

I have a program that iterates over all lines of a text file, adds spaces between the characters, and writes the output to the same file. However, if there are multiple lines in the input, I want the output to have separate lines as well. I tried:

```
let text = format!(r"{}\n", line); // Add newline character to each line (while iterating)
file.write_all(text.as_bytes()); // Write each line + newline
```

Here is an example input text file:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

And its output:

```
f o o\n b a r\n b a z
```

It seems that Rust treats `"\n"` as an escaped `n` character, but using `r"\n"` treats it as a string. How can I have Rust treat `\n` as a newline character to write multiple lines to a text file?

Note: I can include the rest of my code if you need it, let me know.

Edit: I am on Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the 'r' in front of your string. Remove it and your program will print newlines instead of '\n'.

Also note that only most Unices use '\n' as newline. Windows uses "\r\n".

Comment: I tried it, but instead it just writes it all on one line, just without the `\n`'s.

Comment: Windows will not show `\n` as newlines. Try `\r\n` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it shows up after removing the `r` and adding `\r\n`.